# SqlPackage.exe export/import database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlpackage

After the migration of Azure to database to V12 preview using SqlPackage.exe to export and the import the DB to the local machine I obtain the error:

```
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.


Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE TYPE [sys].[script_deployment_databases] AS TABLE (
    [logical_server] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [database_name]  [sysname] NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([database_name] ASC, [logical_server] ASC));
```

Infact there's a User-Defined Table type looking in Management Studio that canno be dropped.

How to solve?

I tried exporting with all the options using [this script](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/65815DF4/325CE40C).

Answer (score 1):

Other people had this problem recently crop up [(link)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b37d868-3106-4358-b7a6-a50d0890f079/sql-azure-import-of-bacpac-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-v12?forum=ssdsgetstarted).

The problem was that Microsoft's migration of certain databases accidentally created the "errant object" `sys.script_deployment_databases`: a table type definition that uses the sys schema but is marked with metadata `is_user_defined = 1`. The fact that it's "user defined" causes bacpacs to contain it. Attempts to restore the bacpac fail because it tries to create it under sys.

Microsoft recently updated their DacFx and SSDT tools (as well as the Azure portal) to apparently ignore this errant object when exporting/importing bacpacs.

On a related note: Deploying dacpacs to upgrade such an afflicted database has a similar issue, where on a deployment attempt it tries to drop and re-create all "user defined table types" and fails because `script_deployment_databases` is under sys. However, currently the tooling has not been fixed for dacpacs yet.

One technique to remove the `script_deployment_databases` object is to copy the database directly using `CREATE DATABASE [X] AS COPY OF [Y]` , then rename them so that the copy replaces the original. The object is apparently omitted from copies.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install an update for Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework. It can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45886)

The thread and response from Microsoft can be found at the following [link](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/azure/sqlazure.aspx?ID=5b37d868-3106-4358-b7a6-a50d0890f079)

Here's the response from Raul Garcia - MS:

> Update (as of 2015-March-2):
>
> The fixes for exporting and importing bacpacs from a V12-upgraded
>   Azure SQL Database server have been deployed. You should be able to
>   export/import successfully through the Azure portal, and you can
>   install this updated version of DacFx to export/import through SSMS,
>   SSDT, SqlPackage.exe, or the DacFx API.
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45886
>
> (Note: You must install BOTH the x64 and x86 versions of the MSIs if
>   you are on an x64 machine.)
>
> Thank you for your patience.
>   -Raul Garcia